# Transforming Binary Column is Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

What is the best way to transform a binary column in Spark Dataframe, here are the details:

I have a Kafka stream which has this structure: [Kafka Schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

```scala
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
```

I want to use `from_avro` function but I have to get the bytes after the fifth element because of Kafka wire protocol. `from_avro` function gets a column and a schema and returns a new column.

```scala
val jsonSchema = ??? // I have the schema
df.select(
    col("key").cast("string"), 
    col("value")
      .as("binaryValue"),
    from_avro(col("value"), jsonSchema)
      .as("avro")
)
```

I basically want to convert `col("value")` to another column that each array of bytes starts from the fifth element, e.g. in Scala `arrayValue.slice(4, arrayValue.length)`

Comment: any specific reason why you want slice data ?? can you add same data

Comment: add? The bytes should get sliced because of Kafka wire protocol

Comment: with out slice how you are getting data ? & can you add schema ?

Comment: I have everything ready, the schema, the binary column, all I have to do is a function from Column to Column that gets the binary data and slices it